# Post MacOS Big Sur fail - java.awt.robot.createScreenCapture now only captures desktop

Tags: screen-capture, awtrobot, macos-big-sur

MacOS after installing Big Sur update. Any help on this much appreciated.

**Before:**

Calling java.awt.robot.createScreenCapture

Results in:

Screenshot of whatever is currently visible

**After:**

Calling java.awt.robot.createScreenCapture

Results in:

screenshot of desktop

Simple code to test this:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScreenCaptureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 500));
        File file = new File("screenCapture.png"); 
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        // Captures part of desktop, not current windows in focus :(
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a work-around that does what I need. Takes a screenshot of screens with current focus (and not the Desktop).

May help someone else.

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.delay(200);
        renameCaptureAs(filename);
```